# JSTL c:set with scope as 'application'

Tags: scope, jstl

I have a variable set using c:set as below in x.jsp

```
<c:set var="map" value="${map}" scope="application">
```

In y.jsp I am using variable map to build a mulit select dropdown

```
<c:foreach items="${maps}" var="map">
   <option>map</option>
</c:foreach>
```

The values in the second file show up but not on the first page load. It appears that the maps variable is not available for the second jsp on first load. But once I refresh the page, I am able to populate values in the second jsp.

What am I missing? I just want to be able to get maps in the second jsp file. Are there better ways of achieving the same? TIA

Comment: You click the link with this `jsp` file going to the second page?

Comment: There's a workaround here may solve your problem: `response.setIntHeader("Refresh", 5);`, add it to your second jsp, the page will be refreshed in 5 seconds, you can specify any value you want.

Comment: @Sky Actually, both the jsps are loaded at the same time. First jsp is rendering some UI components and the second jsp is rendering the rest. I am using the variable of first jsp to populate the dropdown in the second jsp.

Comment: Is the second jsp include into first one? What's the relation between these two jsp files?